# Unkown result with TCP/IP with NWConnection in swift

Tags: swift, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I'm coding a socket connection for a server which says:

> EthMan uses raw TCP/IP connections (not HTTP) for remote management
>   and statistics. Optionally, "psw" field is added to requests is the
>   password for remote management is set for miner. The following
>   commands are available (JSON format):

I have tried a lot of libraries and none of them worked for me!!
the best result that I got is with NWConnection.

```
func startSocket() {

        let connection = NWConnection(host: "xxxx.com", port: 3405, using: .tcp)

        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
            print("State:", state)
            switch state {
                case .ready:
                    self.connectionReady(connection)
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
        connection.start(queue: .main)
    }

    func connectionReady(_ connection: NWConnection) {

        let raw = """
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Upgrade: websocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Host: echo.websocket.org
    Origin: https://echo.websocket.org
    Sec-WebSocket-Key: s04nPqA7M6pQ3Lu2jRJLSQ==
    Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
    """

        let rawData = raw.appending("\n\n\n").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\r\n").data(using: .utf8)

        connection.send(content: rawData!, completion: .idempotent)

        connection.receiveMessage(completion: {data, context, bool, error in
            if let data = data {
                print("Received:", String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) )

            }
            print("Error:", error)

            let hello = "Hello".data(using: .utf8)
            connection.send(content: hello, completion: .idempotent)
        })
    }
```

I call the startSocket in viewDidLoad and I get the following as a result in the console:
(There s "result in the response which is the JSON result that I'm looking for)

> Received: Optional("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n\r\n{\"result\":
>   [\"15.0 - ETH\", \"11696\", \"379693;65021;3\",
>   \"32232;27450;32361;31777;31914;31795;31959;32371;32241;32321;31483;31784\",
>   \"0;0;0\", \"off;off;off;off;off;off;off;off;off;off;off;off\",
>   \"65;73;61;56;61;67;57;53;51;51;61;64;61;75;62;54;57;54;61;49;51;49;58;53\",
>   \"us1.ethermine.org:4444\", \"22;47;0;0\",
>   \"5361;4628;5324;5304;5487;5413;5278;5411;5491;5420;5237;5383\",
>   \"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;0\", \"13;2;1;1;0;1;0;0;0;2;2;0\",
>   \"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0\", \"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0\",
>   \"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0\", \"1;2;6;7;8;12;13;14;15;16;17;18\",
>   \"31;408;9734\", \"792\"]}
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.780 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65015, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.234 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.458 Mh/s, GPU2 32.372 Mh/s, GPU3 31.790 Mh/s, GPU4 31.954 Mh/s, GPU5 31.796 Mh/s, GPU6 31.955 Mh/s, GPU7 32.377 Mh/s, GPU8 32.241
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.338 Mh/s, GPU10 31.465 Mh/s, GPU11 31.801
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:22:46 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.796 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65015, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.211 Mh/s, GPU1 27.461 Mh/s, GPU2 32.376
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.783 Mh/s, GPU4 31.959 Mh/s, GPU5 31.802 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.964 Mh/s, GPU7 32.367 Mh/s, GPU8 32.244 Mh/s, GPU9 32.343 Mh/s, GPU10 31.486 Mh/s, GPU11 31.801 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:22:46 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 377.920 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65015, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.063 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.366 Mh/s, GPU2 32.077 Mh/s, GPU3 31.556 Mh/s, GPU4 31.885 Mh/s, GPU5 31.720 Mh/s, GPU6 31.734 Mh/s, GPU7 32.239 Mh/s, GPU8 31.914
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.317 Mh/s, GPU10 31.457 Mh/s, GPU11 31.590
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:22:50 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.638 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65015, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.222 Mh/s, GPU1 27.447 Mh/s, GPU2 32.351
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.776 Mh/s, GPU4 31.945 Mh/s, GPU5 31.785 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.935 Mh/s, GPU7 32.373 Mh/s, GPU8 32.226 Mh/s, GPU9 32.322 Mh/s, GPU10 31.469 Mh/s, GPU11 31.787 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:22:53 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.788 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65015, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.241 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.458 Mh/s, GPU2 32.368 Mh/s, GPU3 31.787 Mh/s, GPU4 31.952 Mh/s, GPU5 31.805 Mh/s, GPU6 31.955 Mh/s, GPU7 32.368 Mh/s, GPU8 32.247
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.340 Mh/s, GPU10 31.478 Mh/s, GPU11 31.789
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:22:56 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.733 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65015, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.231 Mh/s, GPU1 27.458 Mh/s, GPU2 32.367
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.789 Mh/s, GPU4 31.944 Mh/s, GPU5 31.786 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.951 Mh/s, GPU7 32.363 Mh/s, GPU8 32.240 Mh/s, GPU9 32.339 Mh/s, GPU10 31.474 Mh/s, GPU11 31.791 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:22:56 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.733 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65015, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.231 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.458 Mh/s, GPU2 32.367 Mh/s, GPU3 31.789 Mh/s, GPU4 31.944 Mh/s, GPU5 31.786 Mh/s, GPU6 31.951 Mh/s, GPU7 32.363 Mh/s, GPU8 32.240
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.339 Mh/s, GPU10 31.474 Mh/s, GPU11 31.791
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:22:58 -
>   SHARE FOUND - (GPU 9)\n
> ETH: Share
>   accepted (1422 ms)!\r\n
> ETH:
>   02/08/20-15:23:00 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.764 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65016, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.235 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.453 Mh/s, GPU2 32.371 Mh/s, GPU3 31.790 Mh/s, GPU4 31.951 Mh/s, GPU5 31.801 Mh/s, GPU6 31.954 Mh/s, GPU7 32.371 Mh/s, GPU8 32.235
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.330 Mh/s, GPU10 31.479 Mh/s, GPU11 31.796
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:02 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.835 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65016, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.240 Mh/s, GPU1 27.455 Mh/s, GPU2 32.373
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.793 Mh/s, GPU4 31.957 Mh/s, GPU5 31.803 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.962 Mh/s, GPU7 32.371 Mh/s, GPU8 32.243 Mh/s, GPU9 32.346 Mh/s, GPU10 31.485 Mh/s, GPU11 31.806 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:02 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.835 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65016, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.240 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.455 Mh/s, GPU2 32.373 Mh/s, GPU3 31.793 Mh/s, GPU4 31.957 Mh/s, GPU5 31.803 Mh/s, GPU6 31.962 Mh/s, GPU7 32.371 Mh/s, GPU8 32.243
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.346 Mh/s, GPU10 31.485 Mh/s, GPU11 31.806
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:05 -
>   SHARE FOUND - (GPU 4)\n
> ETH: Share
>   accepted (79 ms)!\r\n
> ETH:
>   02/08/20-15:23:06 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 4)\n
> ETH: Share accepted (94 ms)!\r\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:06 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.623 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65018, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.225 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.436 Mh/s, GPU2 32.354 Mh/s, GPU3 31.784 Mh/s, GPU4 31.939 Mh/s, GPU5 31.776 Mh/s, GPU6 31.939 Mh/s, GPU7 32.354 Mh/s, GPU8 32.227
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.324 Mh/s, GPU10 31.467 Mh/s, GPU11 31.797
>   Mh/s\n
> GPU0 t=65C fan=75% P=66W,
>   GPU1 t=61C fan=55% P=61W, GPU2 t=61C fan=67% P=65W, GPU3 t=57C fan=53%
>   P=66W, GPU4 t=52C fan=50% P=67W, GPU5 t=61C fan=61% P=65W, GPU6 t=61C
>   fan=75% P=67W, GPU7 t=62C fan=55% P=66W, GPU8 t=57C fan=54% P=67W,
>   GPU9 t=61C fan=50% P=66W, GPU10 t=51C fan=49% P=68W, GPU11 t=58C
>   fan=52% P=66W\n
> Total GPUs power
>   consumption: 790 Watts\n
> ETH:
>   02/08/20-15:23:08 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 5)\n
> ETH: Share accepted (94 ms)!\r\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:10 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.726 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65019, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.232 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.458 Mh/s, GPU2 32.376 Mh/s, GPU3 31.788 Mh/s, GPU4 31.923 Mh/s, GPU5 31.795 Mh/s, GPU6 31.923 Mh/s, GPU7 32.372 Mh/s, GPU8 32.239
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.342 Mh/s, GPU10 31.479 Mh/s, GPU11 31.798
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:12 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.803 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65019, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.241 Mh/s, GPU1 27.453 Mh/s, GPU2 32.369
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.789 Mh/s, GPU4 31.953 Mh/s, GPU5 31.801 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.958 Mh/s, GPU7 32.371 Mh/s, GPU8 32.246 Mh/s, GPU9 32.337 Mh/s, GPU10 31.486 Mh/s, GPU11 31.800 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:13 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.765 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65019, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.239 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.449 Mh/s, GPU2 32.347 Mh/s, GPU3 31.790 Mh/s, GPU4 31.953 Mh/s, GPU5 31.801 Mh/s, GPU6 31.954 Mh/s, GPU7 32.376 Mh/s, GPU8 32.229
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.343 Mh/s, GPU10 31.482 Mh/s, GPU11 31.802
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:14 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.758 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65019, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.236 Mh/s, GPU1 27.448 Mh/s, GPU2 32.368
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.791 Mh/s, GPU4 31.953 Mh/s, GPU5 31.801 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.944 Mh/s, GPU7 32.373 Mh/s, GPU8 32.244 Mh/s, GPU9 32.332 Mh/s, GPU10 31.463 Mh/s, GPU11 31.805 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:14 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.758 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65019, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.236 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.448 Mh/s, GPU2 32.368 Mh/s, GPU3 31.791 Mh/s, GPU4 31.953 Mh/s, GPU5 31.801 Mh/s, GPU6 31.944 Mh/s, GPU7 32.373 Mh/s, GPU8 32.244
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.332 Mh/s, GPU10 31.463 Mh/s, GPU11 31.805
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:17 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.744 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65019, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.238 Mh/s, GPU1 27.461 Mh/s, GPU2 32.368
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.786 Mh/s, GPU4 31.955 Mh/s, GPU5 31.798 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.924 Mh/s, GPU7 32.363 Mh/s, GPU8 32.237 Mh/s, GPU9 32.335 Mh/s, GPU10 31.480 Mh/s, GPU11 31.798 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:17 - New job from
>   us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total
>   Speed: 379.744 Mh/s, Total Shares: 65019, Rejected: 3, Time:
>   194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.238 Mh/s, GPU1
>   27.461 Mh/s, GPU2 32.368 Mh/s, GPU3 31.786 Mh/s, GPU4 31.955 Mh/s, GPU5 31.798 Mh/s, GPU6 31.924 Mh/s, GPU7 32.363 Mh/s, GPU8 32.237
>   Mh/s, GPU9 32.335 Mh/s, GPU10 31.480 Mh/s, GPU11 31.798
>   Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:19 - New
>   job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.538 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65019, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.213 Mh/s, GPU1 27.434 Mh/s, GPU2 32.348
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.762 Mh/s, GPU4 31.923 Mh/s, GPU5 31.799 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.929 Mh/s, GPU7 32.359 Mh/s, GPU8 32.229 Mh/s, GPU9 32.325 Mh/s, GPU10 31.458 Mh/s, GPU11 31.759 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:20 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU
>   8)\n
> ETH: Share accepted (547
>   ms)!\r\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:24 -
>   New job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.770 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65020, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.234 Mh/s, GPU1 27.457 Mh/s, GPU2 32.367
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.789 Mh/s, GPU4 31.946 Mh/s, GPU5 31.795 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.961 Mh/s, GPU7 32.368 Mh/s, GPU8 32.237 Mh/s, GPU9 32.339 Mh/s, GPU10 31.480 Mh/s, GPU11 31.796 Mh/s\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:26 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU
>   3)\n
> ETH: Share accepted (454
>   ms)!\r\n
> ETH: 02/08/20-15:23:26 -
>   New job from us1.ethermine.org:4444\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.780 Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65021, Rejected: 3, Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.236 Mh/s, GPU1 27.460 Mh/s, GPU2 32.378
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.775 Mh/s, GPU4 31.959 Mh/s, GPU5 31.802 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.957 Mh/s, GPU7 32.363 Mh/s, GPU8 32.235 Mh/s, GPU9 32.334 Mh/s, GPU10 31.478 Mh/s, GPU11 31.803 Mh/s\n
> \n
> GPU #0:
>   Ellesmere (Radeon RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units
>   (pci bus 1:0:0)\n
> GPU #1: Ellesmere
>   (Radeon RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   2:0:0)\n
> GPU #2: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   6:0:0)\n
> GPU #3: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   7:0:0)\n
> GPU #4: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   8:0:0)\n
> GPU #5: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   12:0:0)\n
> GPU #6: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   13:0:0)\n
> GPU #7: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   14:0:0)\n
> GPU #8: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   15:0:0)\n
> GPU #9: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   16:0:0)\n
> GPU #10: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   17:0:0)\n
> GPU #11: Ellesmere (Radeon
>   RX 580 Series), 8192 MB available, 36 compute units (pci bus
>   18:0:0)\n
> ETH - Total Speed: 379.693
>   Mh/s, Total Shares:
>   65021(5472+4713+5434+5401+5587+5536+5404+5533+5589+5529+5335+5488),
>   Rejected: 3(0+0+0+0+0+0+0+1+2+0+0+0), Time: 194:56\n
> ETH: GPU0 32.232 Mh/s, GPU1 27.450 Mh/s, GPU2 32.361
>   Mh/s, GPU3 31.777 Mh/s, GPU4 31.914 Mh/s, GPU5 31.796 Mh/s, GPU6
>   31.960 Mh/s, GPU7 32.372 Mh/s, GPU8 32.241 Mh/s, GPU9 32.321 Mh/s, GPU10 31.484 Mh/s, GPU11 31.784 Mh/s\n
> Incorrect ETH shares: GPU0 13, GPU1 2, GPU2 1, GPU3
>   1, GPU5 1, GPU9 2, GPU10 2\n
>  1
>   minute average ETH total speed: 379.503 Mh/s\n
> Pool switches: ETH - 47\n
> Pool shares accepting time (1 hour stats) - min 31
>   ms, max 9734 ms, average 408 ms\n
> Current ETH share target: 0x0000000112e0be82 (diff:
>   4000MH), epoch 314(3.45GB)\n
> Current
>   -dcri values: -dcri 12,14,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,16,14,12\n
> GPU0 t=65C fan=73% P=66W, GPU1 t=61C fan=56% P=61W,
>   GPU2 t=61C fan=67% P=65W, GPU3 t=57C fan=53% P=67W, GPU4 t=51C fan=51%
>   P=67W, GPU5 t=61C fan=64% P=65W, GPU6 t=61C fan=75% P=67W, GPU7 t=62C
>   fan=54% P=66W, GPU8 t=57C fan=54% P=67W, GPU9 t=61C fan=49% P=66W,
>   GPU10 t=51C fan=49% P=68W, GPU11 t=58C fan=53% P=66W\n
> Total GPUs power consumption: 791
>   Watts\n
> \n
> ") Error: nil 2020-02-08
>   15:23:39.892507+0330 test sockett[11440:3582963] [] tcp_input [C1.1:1]
>   flags=[R.] seq=3417871573, ack=29798303, win=0 state=CLOSE_WAIT
>   rcv_nxt=3417871573, snd_una=29798298

It contains what I want, but I have no clue what to do with this!!!! I think it is a combination of HTML and something else !!! I'M NOT SURE

and then it says:

> State: failed(POSIXErrorCode: Connection reset by peer)